# Maven release create tag based on version

Tags: maven, release

Using maven release:prepare simplifies the process of deploying an artifact. It is possible to define the tag with `tag` tag. The plugin allows to use properties to build a customized tag-name.

But I need a more customized version, which used "_" insteat of points for delimeters in version. e.g. version: 1.0.1.2 => tagname should be 01_01_01 .

If I could access the majorVersion, minorVersion of ${project.version} this would be a solution too. But it seems that they are not available general.

[build-helper plugin seems to be no solution since I call `release:prepare` and therefore any settings by this plugins will be lost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002033/create-property-with-string-format/12002359#12002359).

Any ideas how to achieve this in an easy manner?

Comment: First why would you need that? Why not using the defaults. Extracting the information version infos can be extracted by the build number plugin.

Comment: @khmarbaise his issue is that he wants to control the tag name that release:prepare tags his SCM with and http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html#tagNameFormat is not flexible enough for him

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way is to always run maven like so

```
mvn validate release:prepare
```

Of course if you forget to invoke `validate` prior to release:prepare your release will be borked... so that's no good.

The next improvement is to have a profile with defaultGoals

```
<profile>
  <id>prepare-release</id>
  <build>
    <defaultGoal>validate release:prepare</defaultGoal>
  </build>
</profile>
```

Then you release by doing the *non-standard*

```
mvn -Pprepare-release
```

The true fix would be to suggest a patch to the maven release plugin to allow regex like replacement in the [tagNameFormat](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html#tagNameFormat) configuration parameter.

Comment: Thank you. This is working for me. (Doing crazy things with the building-helper plugin, but if this is the maven way ... ;-))

Answer (score 0):

Using Maven-Release Plugin, you can specify the format of the tag you want.
Maven Release Plugin run 2 goals:
release:prepare and release:perform.

Here you have the necessary targets in your root pom:
http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/usage.html

and If you are using Jenkins tool, you can use the Maven Release Plugin to run it,
or just run it manually mvn release:prepare and mvn release:perform