# Maven, automating the version change

Tags: maven, build-automation, release-management

Let's say I have a pom file,

```
<version>14.4.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

which defines a version of the project to build. This value is updated automatically by our build system (jenkins).

Later on, in one of the plugins, I need to have a property, which incorporates the first two figures from the version, so that for 14.4.1-SNAPSHOT value, it would be "14.4", and for 13.12.39-SNAPSHOT value it would be "13.12".

Currently we update this value manually each month:

```
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-cli</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/14.4/changeLog.xml</changeLogFile>
```

Ideally, I would love to have instead something like

```
<changeLogFile>src/main/resources/${releaseVersion}/changeLog.xml</changeLogFile>
```

But how would I get this `${releaseVersion}` (=14.4) calculated automatically from the `<version>14.4.1-SNAPSHOT</version>` ?

In that case it is absolutely automated, and we do not have any manual process in place.
Is there any expressions-kind-of-language I can use in pom files, which could parse the string  `14.4.1-SNAPSHOT` and produce from it an `14.4` ?

Comment: can you change the parent pom ?

Comment: oh, and how do you currently increase the version? via maven release?

Comment: @LordT yes, i think i can, it depends on what is to change there. why?

Comment: @LortT yes, we have a job in jenkins, triggered manually/periodically. doesn't matter. I would like to avoid including the changing of my version for this small plugin in the release process..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try the mojo build-helper with parse-version for this.

[Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002033/in-maven-how-can-i-dynamically-build-a-property-value-at-runtime)

[Original Documentation](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/parse-version-mojo.html)

[Edit] Here's my example pom.xml:

```
<build>

 <plugins>
  <plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.2</version>
  <configuration>
  <webResources>
    <resource>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
     <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
    <directory>src/main/resources/${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.${parsedVersion.minorVersion}</directory>
    </resource>
</webResources>
</configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
      <phase>validate</phase>
        <id>parse-version</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>parse-version</goal>
        </goals>
         <configuration>
        <propertyPrefix>parsedVersion</propertyPrefix>
    </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>validate</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>run</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <tasks>
                        <echo>Major: ${parsedVersion.majorVersion}</echo>
                        <echo>Minor: ${parsedVersion.minorVersion}</echo>
                        <echo>Incremental: ${parsedVersion.incrementalVersion}</echo>
                        <echo>Qualifier: ${parsedVersion.qualifier}</echo>
                        <echo>BuildNumber: ${parsedVersion.buildNumber}</echo>
                    </tasks>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Many thanks, that's what i was looking for... maybe need to improve my search skills before posting a question :)