# Javadoc with Java17 gives package X is declared in module Y error

Tags: java, javadoc, maven-javadoc-plugin

I'm using maven-javadoc-plugin to produce Javadoc with Java 17. Since there is a class in my code that uses jdk.internal.reflect.Reflection class, Javadoc gives an error. I tried using  to pass --add-opens flag but it's no use.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-javadocs</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals><goal>jar</goal></goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

It get the error below.

```
import jdk.internal.reflect.Reflection;
[ERROR]                    ^
[ERROR]   (package jdk.internal.reflect is declared in module java.base, which does not 
export it to the unnamed module)
[ERROR] 1 error
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Command line was: cmd.exe /X /C ""C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.1\bin\javadoc.exe" @options @packages"
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone struggling, maven-javadoc-plugin's documentation says use the additionalOption tag with -J flag([ref](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html#additionalJOptions)) but in my case it didn't pass the flag. So I used the plugin with the configuration below:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <configuration>
    <additionalJOption>
       --add-exports java.base/jdk.internal.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED
    </additionalJOption>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-javadocs</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals><goal>jar</goal></goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: this does not work. I tested with maven-javadoc-plugin 3.6.2.

Comment: only working work around for me is

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround I was able to get together is this:

```
<plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.6.2</version>
      <configuration>
        <!-- this is a workaround until accessing not exported packages is available for javadoc-->
        <!-- see the following -->
        <!-- https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8212233?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel -->
        <!-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62206112/maven-javadoc-plugin-how-to-update-the-module-path-dynamically -->
        <!-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73893137/javadoc-with-java17-gives-package-x-is-declared-in-module-y-error -->
        <source>8</source>
        <target>8</target>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
```